# Angular cannot pass data to custom directive

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, geojson

My Directive

```
angular
    .module('directoryAppMap')
    .directive('leafletDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                data:'='     //I try to pass data by this scope//
            },
            replace:true,
            template:'<div></div>',
            link: function (scope,element, attrs) {
                var map = L.map(attrs.id, {
                    center: [40, -86],
                    zoom: 2
                });
                //create a CloudMade tile layer and add it to the map
                L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
                    maxZoom: 18
                }).addTo(map);

                scope.ho = ["geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2.0, 2.0 ] } },
                    { "type": "Feature",  "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } },

                ];
                    L.geoJson(scope.ho).addTo(map);
            }

        };
    });
```

But when i Try to pass data from my view

```
<tr ng-repeat="hf in (FilteredGeojson = (ho))">
<div leaflet-directive id="map" data="FilteredGeojson"></div>
```

The scope is the same, the difference is that i initialize it in controller not in directive and then when i pass FilteredGeojson to leaflet it show me invalid geojson object.

I even throw away all filters in order to just pass some data, Maybe i do something wrong with directive and global scope?

My geojson is valid i check it plenty of times, should i pass data to leaflet in some other way? For me is important that map and table are integrated dynamically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs, cannot pass data to geojsonLayer Leaflet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441363/angularjs-cannot-pass-data-to-geojsonlayer-leaflet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've stripped out the `L` methods and noticed it wasn't working due to partial code

```
<tr ng-repeat="hf in FilteredGeojson = (ho)">
<div leaflet-directive id="map" data="FilteredGeojson"></div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4zWwDP0SaTYCB54k8CEc?p=preview

Comment: The problem is it can work with simple table, but with leaflet and factory not

Comment: can you recreate it on plunk?

Comment: actually if found some solution, but is not perfect,    
       <div ng-init="FilteredGeojson = (data | filter:search)">
       <tr ng-repeat="hf in FilteredGeojson">, but filter is not working, it is possible to make filtering on ng-init?

Comment: It's possible but it's most likely not working on init because `data` is empty at the time when filter is executed. Although that SHOULD work `<tr ng-repeat="hf in FilteredGeojson = (data | filter:search)">`

Comment: actually i dont know what you mean, that data is empty because in controller i create scope.data with geojson array, the problem is when i do like you wrote then i have infinite digest loop and zero markers, i found somewhere that making ng-init could solve it

Comment: i tried once more like this <tr ng-repeat="hf in FilteredGeojson = data | filter:search"> no errors works fine, beside one when i pass FilteredGeojson to directive by scope, map is empty? What could be the reason of that?

Comment: i made new question with fiddler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28464558/ng-repeat-causing-infinitive-digest-loop-when-passing-scope-to-leaflet-directive